# jquery forEach function used to show / list dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 3 dynamic buttons with class attribute and would like them listed when one is clicked. Only one is shown rather than all three.

```
<script>
var hyperlink;

$(function() {
    var y = 2;

    for(var i = 0; i <= 2; i++ ) {
         drawRow( i,  y );
    }
});

function drawRow( x, y ) {

    if(x == 0)
        row = $("<tr />")

    else {

        var btnName = "btn" + x;
        console.log("ln62 btnName: " + btnName);
        hyperlink = document.createElement("button");
        hyperlink.setAttribute('id', btnName);          
        hyperlink.setAttribute('class', 'btnCL');      //  class set for button
        hyperlink.innerHTML = x;

        $("#DataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td></td>").append(hyperlink));
        var btnName2 = "#btn" + x;
    }
}

$(document).on("click", '.btnCL', function() {

    console.log("inside doc.on ln73");
    //console.log("hyperlink: " + hyperlink.getAttribute("id"));
    $(hyperlink).each(function( i ) {
           console.log("ln76 " + i + ": " + hyperlink.getAttribute("id"));           
    });

});

</script>
```

Result:
ln62 btnName: btn1
ln62 btnName: btn2
ln62 btnName: btn3

inside doc.on ln73
ln76 0: btn3            // only one(1) listed??    s/b 3

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I would like to help you but your code has a lot of mistakes. Place a working code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because  `hyperlink` is a variable and not an array.This line `hyperlink = document.createElement("button");` will always update `hyperlink` variable with last created button.

Instead of using `each` you can use the `event` object and get the target

```js
var hyperlink;

$(function() {
  var y = 2;

  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    drawRow(i, y);
  }
});

function drawRow(x, y) {

  if (x == 0)
    row = $("<tr />")

  else {

    var btnName = "btn" + x;
    console.log("ln62 btnName: " + btnName);
    hyperlink = document.createElement("button");
    hyperlink.setAttribute('id', btnName);
    hyperlink.setAttribute('class', 'btnCL'); //  class set for button
    hyperlink.innerHTML = x;

    $("#DataTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<td></td>").append(hyperlink));
    var btnName2 = "#btn" + x;
  }
}

$(document).on("click", '.btnCL', function(e) {
  console.log("inside doc.on ln73");
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="DataTable"></table>
```

Comment: `e.target.getAttribute("id")` can be simplified to `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is every iteration of the loop you reassign a new value to the variable `hyperlink`

All you really need to do is loop over the class collection and you don't need the global variable at all

```
$(document).on("click", '.btnCL', function() {
   // current button is `this`
   console.log('Current id:', this.id);

   // loop over the class instead to see them all 
    $('.btnCL').each(function( i, el ) {
           console.log("ln76 " + i + ": " + el.id); // or this.id          
    });    
});
```